# Configuring a multi mode Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up a multi node cluster I have 3 machines with one acting as the namenode and datanode and the other two acting as datanode . I have different user names for all the machines, node1 has the username hdfsadmin , node2 has the username hduser and node 3 also has username hduser . 
The problem is that Hadoop throws a connection refused error when I try to connect to the datanode as it expects the same name for the datanodes as the namenode which is different in my case. How do I solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u share exact logs?

Comment: Have you configured passwordless ssh between these nodes and users..?

Comment: Yes I did configure it, but in order to ssh between two machines you need to specify the usernames as well, for eg. ssh hostname would assume the hostname of the machine you are currently logged into , in order to ssh to the other machine with a different username we would need to run ssh username@hostname, and this is where the problem lies .

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not necessary to have the same host name for all nodes.
Please cross check following:

1) Make sure, you are able to ssh the other node.

2) Make sure, you define all host names in /etc/hosts file with IP address.

```
 hadoopmnmaster   192.168.56.11
 hadoopmnslave1   192.168.56.12
 hadoopmnslave2   192.168.56.13
 hadoopmnslave3   192.168.56.14
```

3) Make entry to master/slave nodes in master/slave file in the conf directory.

4) Make sure, daemons are running on each node.

If all above is up to the mark, then your cluster should run fine.

Comment: I am talking about the user name ,not the host name.

Answer (score 1):

You should update each of the ssh key 
'ssh-keygen -R username' 
it will update all the ssh keys and u will be authorized to access